# Find value with multiple criteria

Tags: vba

I need to find a value in Excel sheet based on 2 criteria.
Find method support only one criteria.
Is there  any other function?
For example there is 2 columns. I need to find ABC in column A, where value in column B is 10.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Loop down until find match in two columns.

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? Will an Array Formula work for you? =MATCH("ABC10",B:B&C:C,0) (You enter array formulas with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: I prefer VBa here

Answer (score 0):

First approach that came to mind. Im sure there are other ways and probably better.

```
'VBA Loop Not exactly recommended if the file is long
Set wk = ThisWorkbook
With wk.Sheets("SheetName")
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 to lastRow
        aString = .Cells(i, 1).Text
        bString = .Cells(i, 2).Text
        If aString & bString = "ABC10" Then
            MsgBox "Found at Row: " & i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```